# Comparing values in different columns

Tags: mysql

So what I am trying to accomplish is to get the pairs of great grandkids with the great grandparent. I have a table called `Parents` that contains `child` and `parent` so I need to compare the child and the parents and check to see if its a match. I can do this in java no problem I am just clueless how to do it in mysql. Any help or tips would be awesome

```
child|parent
------------
will |john
john |jim
jim  |joe
```

So I would want to get the values will, joe because will is the great grandkid of joe

Comment: Sounds like you need to go through some SQL basics. This is pretty elementary. It's not easy to answer since you've given zero information on your schema. This isn't the psychic hotline, so you'll need to provide some context.

Comment: content has been aded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is join the `Parents` table in either of these two orders:

- great grand parent -> grand parent -> parent
- parent -> grand parent -> great grand parent

Example:

```
SELECT
    GreatGrandParents.parent AS great_grand_parent,
    Parents.child AS great_grand_child
-- GreatGrandParents.parent is the great grand parent.
-- GreatGrandParents.child is the grand parent.
FROM Parents AS GreatGrandParents
-- GrandParents.parent is the grand parent.
-- GrandParents.child is the parent
INNER JOIN Parents AS GrandParents
    ON GrandParents.parent = GreatGrandParents.child
-- Parents.parent is the parent.
-- Parents.child is the great grand kid of great grand parents.
INNER JOIN Parents
    ON Parents.parent = GrandParents.child
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab228/1 for an example. It will result in Joe being the great grand parent of Will.